# SSH Hostbased Authentication not working

Tags: ssh

I have been trying to setup host based auth between 2 of my servers and facing some issues.

My setup is:

**Client**

1. Change in `/etc/ssh/ssh_config`:

   ```
   EnableSSHKeySign yes
   HostbasedAuthentication yes
   ```

**Server**

1. Change in `sshd_config`:

   ```
   HostbasedAuthentication yes
   IgnoreRhosts no
   ```
2. Created a file `/etc/ssh/shosts.equiv` with client IP and username
3. created `/etc/ssh/ssh_known_hosts` with the host name IP address comma separated and public keys of client.

When I try to connect I get the error:

```
debug3: authmethod_lookup hostbased
debug3: remaining preferred:
debug1: No more authentication methods to try.
Permission denied (publickey,gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic,password,hostbased).
```

Any hints how to proceed further?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Read the server log  (/var/log/messages, /var/log/secure and/or /var/log/auth.log, depending on distribution and version) and see what `sshd` logged as the rejection reason.